# Simulated Cartpole Example in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am interested in modifying the code underlying the reinforcement learning example *SimulatedCartpole* in Mathematica 12.

This example is still listed as Experimental. The help function indicates that the example in Mathematica is identical to the OpenAI Gym example at https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py

Because I am still learning reinforcement learning, I am interested in playing around with different non-linear dynamics for the differential equations but hoping to use the same state vector and Cart & Pole schema for visualization.

To do this, I was hoping to find, modify the Mathematica code for the example and run it in Mathematica before investing in Python. Anybody know how this might be possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is something similar [SimulatedCartPole](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/SimulatedCartPole.html)  "Reinforcement Learning Environment"